# How to compare pre-post outcome when each subject react differently?

Tags: paired-comparisons

I have 11 subjects with pre and post outcome (two repeated measures).

I'd like to test the difference between both conditions.

The problem is that each subject react very differently. Here's an example :

```
  Subjects Pre-score Post-score

    S646     1.52      8.18
    S657    -1.43     -3.69
    S680     1.57      1.33
    S689     1.46      0.38
    S690     2.02      3.48
    S691     4.26      8.79
    S692     2.20      2.83
    S695    -0.88     -0.28
    S699     5.05      5.13
    S701     2.90      1.04
    S711     2.17      2.09
```

There is something happening, but the mean and a t-test reveal nothing. Is there a way to conceptualize or analyze that kind of "effect" between two conditions on the same subjects ?

If I use the absolute value between the scores, |PostScore - PreScore|, then I use an independent t-test to evaluate if the absolute difference is different from zero, can I say that I examine the magnitude of the effect without consideration of the direction of the effect?

Or maybe, I can use an effect size with that kind of data, with pre-post or repeated measures ?

In fact, I'm interested by the magnitude of the effect, not by the direction.

Comment: I don't quite understand the data. Can you put some column headings? What are the 4 numbers, separated by 2 commas and a space?

Comment: @qoheleth They're *two* numbers per row separated by a space each number with a [decimal comma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark#Countries_using_Arabic_numerals_with_decimal_comma). So "1.52" is written "1,52". Many countries use them.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it seems like you did what was needed. It is a fact of statistical methods that you don't always get a statistically significant result. In these data, there is evidence of a correlation between the pre and post scores, but there is too much variation to statistically conclude that there is a difference between means. The mean post - pre difference is about 0.75. Is that big enough to be of practical significance? If so, you'll need more data to establish a difference of that magnitude exists, if indeed it holds up under further experimentation.

Comment: If I use the absolute value between the scores, |PostScore - PreScore|, then I use an independent t-test to evaluate if the absolute difference is different from zero, can I say that I examine the magnitude of the effect without consideration of the direction of the effect?

Comment: In short, no. You violate the assumptions of the t-test by taking the absolute values of the differences.